# Installing Linux Mint on a PC with Windows 8 and dual boot

Tags: linux, installation, multi-boot, linux-mint

How do I install Linux Mint 17 on the same computer that is running Windows 8 and then make it dual boot?

Comment: [Here is a install guide](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1556)

Comment: Just install it then repair the windows Bootloader same as always

Answer (score 0):

[This is a good guide for getting started.](http://itsfoss.com/guide-install-linux-mint-16-dual-boot-windows/) The only step I would change would be to choose the option "Install Linux Mint alongside them" instead of choosing your own partitions, it just makes your life easier letting Mint do that for you. Prior to installing it might be a good idea to make sure you have space available to install Mint, you can do that by installing another drive in your computer, or shrinking your existing partition.

Basically, Mint does everything for you, put the CD in, reboot your computer, follow the installer, and it will be setup to dual boot using GRUB. Typing your question into Google would have yielded the same result.